# Converting an object-type column to a dates in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I am working in a project now and the is a column known as 'Date of last recharge' but it's an object-type column but I need to convert it into date formats:

`Date of Last Recharge 
20-10-2018

23-10-2018
04-08-2018
12-09-2018
20-08-2018`

How I went about it was to split each date into it's individual year(y), month(m) and day(d) by using custom functions. But in the process of trying to recombine each of the series into a new column using:

`date(y,m,d)`

But I end up with this error:

`cannot convert the series to (class 'int')`

I'm not even sure if this approach is correct, if you know a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: What is your expected output? also provide  the code which you have tried.

Comment: @PedroLobito, I think No, it looks like OP's  datetime column is `dtype: object` which he requires to `dtype: datetime64[ns]` First

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work ..

```
df['Date_of_Last_Recharge'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Last_Recharge'])
```